# getting live variables with clang's python binding

Tags: c, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, control-flow-graph

I'm writing an analysis tool for C language in Python and I am using clang python binding for this purpose. So far it has been great and I was able to get AST of the C files I have and process them. Now I need to find live variable at a certain point of program. By live variables I mean the variables that are used after that line of code before begin re-assigned. I noticed that clang already has some related code in `liveVariables.h`.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work in the python binding?
How can I call `liveVariables` functions by having the AST and `TranslationUnit`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm interested on it as well.

Comment: @afsantos No I didn't.